# solve a system of nonlinear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve 4 nonlinear equations in matlab.
 i wrote a code using fsolve but it failed to proceed, and wrote another one using solve but after 4 hours of running without a result I stop it myself.
I dont know what else i can use to solve it?
is it solvable at all?

this is the code I wrote using fsolve
x and y are vectors and n is the length of this vectors equal to 1200. nu is degree of freedom equal to 1196.
p(1), p(2)... and p(4) are the unknowns

```
x = data1(:,1);
y = data1(:,2);
n = length(x);

p0 = [0 0 0 0];

options = optimset('Display','iter');
[p,fval] = fsolve(@myfunc,p0,options);
```

myfunc:

```
function F = myfunc(p)
global x y n

r = y-p(1)*x.^3-p(2)*x.^2-p(3)*x-p(4);

F = [sum(x.^3)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^3./r);
     sum(x.^2)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^2./r);
     sum(x.^1)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^1./r);
     sum(x.^0)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^0./r)];
```

Comment: `a, b, c, d` are the unknowns?

Comment: i mean P(1) p(2) .. p(4), I did edit it. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is too stiff for `fsolve`, or you've got a poor starting guess.  The code you have looks fine, however, if you may want to use a parametrized anonymous function:

```
x = data1(:,1);
y = data1(:,2);
n = length(x);

p0 = [0 0 0 0];

options = optimset('Display','iter');
[p,fval] = fsolve(@(p) myfunc(p,x,y,n),p0,options);
```

then `myfunc`:

```
function F = myfunc(p,x,y,n)

r = y-p(1)*x.^3-p(2)*x.^2-p(3)*x-p(4);

F = [sum(x.^3)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^3./r);
     sum(x.^2)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^2./r);
     sum(x.^1)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^1./r);
     sum(x.^0)-(n-4-2)*sum(x.^0./r)];
end
```

Comment: thanks, it helped to converge better. but it extremely depends on initial values. I know the expected amounts of each unknown but need to solve this problem without any pre-knowledge. can you suggest another command to solve it?